# Add the value to the next and previous textbox on dropdown change in html table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to add the data value to the previous input and next input when the dropdown of the same row changes but am unable to add the value input textbox on dropdown change am using this to add the value from the sqlite as present am using a variable to add the value to the textbox .

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/eK8X5/7257/)

HTML:

```
   <table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" id="productanddates" class="border">
        <tbody>
            <tr>
                <td class="Second">
                    <input type="text" name="renewal1" id="renewal1">
                </td>
                <td class="third">
                    <select class="dd" name="Phonenumberdd1" id="Phonenumberdd1">
                        <option value="Select">Select a Option</option>
                        <option value="asd">asd</option>
                        <option value="243">243</option>
                        <option value="test 1 3 ">test 1 3</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td class="forth">
                    <input type="text" name="renewal_by1" id="renewal_by1">
                </td>
                <td class="fifth">
                    <input type="text" name="Renivaul_to1" id="Renivaul_to1" value="">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="Second">
                    <input type="text" name="renewal2" id="renewal2">
                </td>
                <td class="third">
                    <select class="dd" name="Phonenumberdd2" id="Phonenumberdd2">
                        <option value="Select">Select a Option</option>
                        <option value="asd">asd</option>
                        <option value="243">243</option>
                        <option value="test 1 3 ">test 1 3</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td class="forth">
                    <input type="text" name="renewal_by2" id="renewal_by2">
                </td>
                <td class="fifth">
                    <input type="text" name="Renivaul_to2" id="Renivaul_to2" value="">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="Second">
                    <input type="text" name="renewal3" id="renewal3">
                </td>
                <td class="third">
                    <select class="dd" name="Phonenumberdd3" id="Phonenumberdd3">
                        <option value="Select">Select a Option</option>
                        <option value="asd">asd</option>
                        <option value="243">243</option>
                        <option value="test 1 3 ">test 1 3</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td class="forth">
                    <input type="text" name="renewal_by3" id="renewal_by3">
                </td>
                <td class="fifth">
                    <input type="text" name="Renivaul_to3" id="Renivaul_to3" value="">
                </td>
            </tr>
            <tr>
                <td class="Second">
                    <input type="text" name="renewal4" id="renewal4">
                </td>
                <td class="third">
                    <select class="dd" name="Phonenumberdd4" id="Phonenumberdd4">
                        <option value="Select">Select a Option</option>
                        <option value="asd">asd</option>
                        <option value="243">243</option>
                        <option value="test 1 3 ">test 1 3</option>
                    </select>
                </td>
                <td class="forth">
                    <input type="text" name="renewal_by4" id="renewal_by4">
                </td>
                <td class="fifth">
                    <input type="text" name="Renivaul_to4" id="Renivaul_to4" value="">
                </td>
            </tr>
        </tbody>
    </table>
```

JS:

```
  $('#productanddates tr').on('change','[class="dd"]', function(e) {
      var data ="dummy data";
      $(this).prev('td input').val(data);
      $(this).next('td input').val(data);
   });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hope this helps

```
$('#productanddates tr').on('change','[class="dd"]', function(e) {
    var data = $(this).val();
    var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    $tr.find('td:nth-child(1) input').val(data);
    $tr.find('td:nth-child(3) input').val(data);    
 });
```

Comment: hi the above works fine for the first row say im trying to create multiple rows on second the above code does not provide the data in the text box  Demo http://jsfiddle.net/99pvwypp/2/

Comment: and you need to type some thing to create a new row after the data is present also on the text box to create a new row FYI:

Answer (score 2):

Try this code snippets using `parent` and `children`.

```js
 $('#productanddates tr').on('change', '.dd', function(e) {
   var data = "dummy data";
   $(this).parent('td').prev('td').children('input').val(data);
   $(this).parent('td').nextAll('td').children('input').val(data);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table width="100%" border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="5" id="productanddates" class="border">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td class="Second">
        <input type="text" name="renewal1" id="renewal1">
      </td>
      <td class="third">
        <select class="dd" name="Phonenumberdd1" id="Phonenumberdd1">
          <option value="Select">Select a Option</option>
          <option value="asd">asd</option>
          <option value="243">243</option>
          <option value="test 1 3 ">test 1 3</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td class="forth">
        <input type="text" name="renewal_by1" id="renewal_by1">
      </td>
      <td class="fifth">
        <input type="text" name="Renivaul_to1" id="Renivaul_to1" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="Second">
        <input type="text" name="renewal2" id="renewal2">
      </td>
      <td class="third">
        <select class="dd" name="Phonenumberdd2" id="Phonenumberdd2">
          <option value="Select">Select a Option</option>
          <option value="asd">asd</option>
          <option value="243">243</option>
          <option value="test 1 3 ">test 1 3</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td class="forth">
        <input type="text" name="renewal_by2" id="renewal_by2">
      </td>
      <td class="fifth">
        <input type="text" name="Renivaul_to2" id="Renivaul_to2" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="Second">
        <input type="text" name="renewal3" id="renewal3">
      </td>
      <td class="third">
        <select class="dd" name="Phonenumberdd3" id="Phonenumberdd3">
          <option value="Select">Select a Option</option>
          <option value="asd">asd</option>
          <option value="243">243</option>
          <option value="test 1 3 ">test 1 3</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td class="forth">
        <input type="text" name="renewal_by3" id="renewal_by3">
      </td>
      <td class="fifth">
        <input type="text" name="Renivaul_to3" id="Renivaul_to3" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td class="Second">
        <input type="text" name="renewal4" id="renewal4">
      </td>
      <td class="third">
        <select class="dd" name="Phonenumberdd4" id="Phonenumberdd4">
          <option value="Select">Select a Option</option>
          <option value="asd">asd</option>
          <option value="243">243</option>
          <option value="test 1 3 ">test 1 3</option>
        </select>
      </td>
      <td class="forth">
        <input type="text" name="renewal_by4" id="renewal_by4">
      </td>
      <td class="fifth">
        <input type="text" name="Renivaul_to4" id="Renivaul_to4" value="">
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: i have a quick question what about the next to the next textbox

Comment: use `nextAll` instead of `next`

Comment: then that will be applicable to all who come next after that

Comment: Yes It will be applicable for all the next `td` elements. It means next all siblings elements of that parent node.

Answer (score 1):

You are doing it wrong there. The event attachment to select was something fishy and you could have done it in a better way as below:

```
$('#productanddates tr').on('change','.dd', function(e) {
    var data ="dummy data";
    $(this).closest('td').prev().find('input').val(data);
    $(this).closest('td').next().find('input').val(data);
});
```

And to find previous and next inputs you need to first find `select`'s parent using `closest` and then navigate back/forth using `prev/next` and then `find` `input`.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/eK8X5/7264/)**

---

**UPDATE**

To get all the textbox in that row you can do it as below:

```
$('#productanddates tr').on('change','.dd', function(e) {
    var data ="dummy data";
    $(this).closest('td').prevAll().find('input').val(data);
    $(this).closest('td').nextAll().find('input').val(data);
});
```

get using `nextAll` and `prevAll`

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/Guruprasad_Rao/eK8X5/7266/)**

Comment: the texts data will be different and the other next will be different can't use the same